# Heroku syslog drain : too many tcp sessions

Tags: heroku, tcp, rsyslog

I set a logging drain on my Heroku app, to send logs to my other server.
My rsyslogd well receive the logs from Heroku, but after few hours, rsyslog start to drop packets because too many TCP connections are opened:

```
Oct 18 06:28:17 localhost rsyslogd-2079: too many tcp sessions - dropping incoming request [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2079 ]
Oct 18 06:28:24 localhost rsyslogd-2079: too many tcp sessions - dropping incoming request [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2079 ]
Oct 18 06:28:24 localhost rsyslogd-2079: too many tcp sessions - dropping incoming request [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2079 ]
Oct 18 06:28:26 localhost rsyslogd-2079: too many tcp sessions - dropping incoming request [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2079 ]
[...]
```

I try to increase the maximum sessions allowed into the rsyslogd configuration (I set it to 1000, which is normally enough to handle everything).

Same issue, so I increase this value to 3000. I have fewer issues now, but I think 3000 max sessions is paticulary high.

```
$ModLoad imtcp
$InputTCPServerRun 514
$InputTCPMaxSessions 3000
```

Do you think there is another thing to do? Do I need to decrease this number?
Maybe there is something else to do to better deal with logs comming from Heroku LogPlex.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions here? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#creating-your-own-syslog-drain